# Weird Javascript closure bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

Here is some code.

```
function callServiceSync(url, obj) {
    var result = true;
    callServiceOptions(url, obj, function(res){
        result = res;
        alert("RESULT CB: "+JSON.stringify(result));
    }, {async: false});
    alert("RESULT POST-CB: "+JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
}
```

When it runs, the alert box says:

> RESULT CB: {"success":true,"data":"dtrombley"}

(that's what the webservice returns, in reality), and then:

> RESULT POST-CB: true

Why isn't this assignment to the closure variable working?  Am I misunderstanding how JS closures work?

callServiceOptions() is rather longwinded - but the gist of it is that it calls jQuery's $.ajax method with it's last arguments options extended into some default (in this case, async is disable for sync query), and then executes the provided callback.

Is $.ajax() maybe executing something in some kind of way that disables/screws up closures (but **I** call the cb, not $.ajax()!)?   If so, how to fix that?

For completeness (though really this function shouldn't be able to screw things up to my thinking):

```
function callServiceOptions(url, obj, cb, options) {
    optSuccess = options.success;
    optError = options.error;
    opts = {}
    $.extend({},options)
    if (!opts.contentType) {
        opts.contentType = "application/json";
    }
    if (!opts.dataType) {
        opts.dataType = "json";
    }
    if (!opts.data && obj) {
        opts.data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
    if (!opts.processData) {
        opts.processData = false;
    }
    if (!opts.method) {
        opts.method = "POST";
    }
    opts.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (optError) {
            optError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
        if (jqXHR.responseText) {
            responseObj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText)
            if (responseObj && responseObj.message)
            cb({
                success: false,
                message: responseObj.message
            })
            return
        }
        cb({
            success: false,
            message: errorThrown
        });
    };
    opts.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (optSuccess) {
            optSuccess(data,textStatus,jqXHR);
        } 
        cb(data);
    };
    if (url.charAt(0) == '/') {
        url = url.substr(1);
    }
    opts.url = WEBCTX.getBaseURL() + url;

    $.ajax(opts);
}
```

**This is not a duplicate of any question asking how to return a value from an async event.   I have a working callServiceAsync() which does that beautifully.   I am using synchronous mode, if you aren't familiar with it, please take a pass on this question...**

Comment: Quentin - Please read the question more carefully.  I'm not executing an asynchronous call, I'm executing a synchronous call, and the value is getting returned correctly from the jQuery ajax().

Comment: No, there is a synchronous query mode, and that is what I am using.   Please read the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and especially the bit about the "async" option, which I am using.

Comment: If it were async, the alerts would not return in that order, but the opposite.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that says to use synchronous requests...

Comment: Your comments look a bit (fill in a fitting word here) now. ;-)

Comment: If you're going to do sync ajax do it in a web worker.

Comment: @trincot  - Haha yup.   Originally was marked dup, which it def was not.   Funny in hindsight though.   Think leaving them is better, since more info for posterity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is asynchronous.

While you have created an object that looks like `{async: false}`, you are passing it as the 4th argument to `callServiceOptions` so it gets placed in the `options` variable.

You only access that variable twice (`options.success` and `options.error`) so the `async` property is never used for anything (so `$.ajax` uses the default value of `true`).

Adding `console.log(opts)` just before you call `$.ajax(opts);` will show this.

Comment: Ah my mistake. I saw the `extend` logic, I was thinking the options was getting extended into opts.

Comment: @Quantastical, `$.extend` modifies the first argument and returns it, but you don't capture the return value.

Comment: Ook.  So was I.   `$.extend(opts,options)` is what I meant of course.   Shame =)  Works now.

Comment: (So, the order of the alerts are not always linear in the order of execution?  In FF, anyhow...)

Comment: (that's what *asynchronous calls* have as effect: asynchronous events are put on the event queue; but the current running code is first completed and only then the event queue is processed, triggering the call back functions)

Comment: Yes, I understand how async calls work.  However, in this case if you reread my observed behavior you'll see that the second-called alert() was displaying /first/.